# ¿Puedo aumentar la velocidad del cursor en un texbox en visual studio 2010?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

tengo este problema, tengo validado un texbox al ingresar algun codigo en el texbox se inserta un registro en la base de datos, y el codigo es el siguiente:

```
Private Sub TXTCODIGOB_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TXTCODIGOB.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

            Mayus()
            Try
                Dim Datos As String
                Dim Info
                Datos = TXTCODIGOB.Text

                Dim Pres As String
                Dim Cod As String

                Info = Split(Datos, "'")
                Cod = Info(0)
                Pres = Info(1)

                TXTCODIGOB.Text = Cod
                TXTPRESENTACIONB.Text = Pres

                If Me.ValidateChildren = True And TXTPRESENTACIONB.Text <> "" And TXTCODIGOB.Text <> "" Then
                    Try
                        Dim dts As New DCAJA
                        Dim func As New OPCAJA
                        Dim fechacreacion As Date
                        fechacreacion = TXTFECHAB.Text
                        '  dts.gFecha = TXTFECHAB.Value.Date
                        dts.gFecha = fechacreacion
                        dts.gCantidad = TXTUNIDAD.Text
                        dts.gCodigoEmpacador = TXTCODIGOB.Text
                        dts.gNumPresentacion = TXTPRESENTACIONB.Text

                        If func.insertar(dts) Then
                            '  MessageBox.Show("Usuario registrado correctamente", "Guardando registros", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                            TXTCODIGOB.Clear()
                            TXTCODIGOB.Focus()
                            MostrarCaja()
                            MostrarDetalle()
                            TXTCODIGOB.Text = ""
                        Else
                            MessageBox.Show("Codigo No Registrado Intente de Nuevo", "Guardando registros", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                            TXTCODIGOB.Clear()
                            TXTCODIGOB.Focus()
                            MostrarCaja()
                            MostrarDetalle()
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MsgBox("Ya existe el usuario")
                    End Try
                Else
                    If Me.ValidateChildren = True And TXTPRESENTACIONB.Text = "" Then
                        Me.ErrorCodigoB.SetError(sender, "")
                        MessageBox.Show("Inserta la Presentacion", "Guardando registros", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                        'TXTCODIGOB.Text = ""
                    Else
                        Me.ErrorCodigoB.SetError(sender, "")
                        MessageBox.Show("Inserta el Usuario", "Guardando registros", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                        TXTCODIGOB.Text = ""
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("CODIGO NO VALIDO")
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

Pero cuando paso varios codigos a una velocidad acelerada mediante un lector, tarda un poco en actualizarse, le gana la velocidad del codigo al texbox, habrá manera de acelerar la velocidad del cursor del texbox, para que inserte el registro más rapido?, o será que ocupo alguna configuración en mi motor de base de datos en sql server para aumentar la velocidad de inserción de registros.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! keydown es por cada tecla presionada... vos insertas asi?

Comment: Es por un lector de código de barras, al pasar por el lector funciona como tecla presionada y se va insertando automáticamente como en una caja del supermercado

Comment: La verdad si funciona, no le veo nada malo. Si anda lento, tampoco se ve nada que lentifique aca. Si es de db el problema, no lo vamos a poder solucionar sin saber mil cosas mas.. como detalle visual studio 2010 es tu ide, y no es el problema aca